# C# project not honouring F# type `[<NoEquality>]` attribute

Tags: c#, f#

I have a simple F# type as follows:

```
(* Num.fsi *)
namespace FsLib

module Num =
  [<NoEquality>]
  type t

  val of_int : int -> t
  val to_int : t -> int
```

Implementation is trivial as you might imagine, it's just a single-case
discriminated union with an underlying `int`. Now in a C# project in the
same solution I have the following code:

```
// CsTool.cs
using System;
using FsLib;

namespace CsTool {
  class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      Num.t n1 = Num.of_int(1);
      Num.t n2 = Num.of_int(1);

      Console.WriteLine(n1.Equals(n2));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, this is printing `False` instead of failing to compile
or throwing a runtime error. Any idea why this C# calling code is
ignoring the `[<NoEquality>]` attribute?

By the way I am running this in Xamarin Studio Community on Mac, version 6.1.2, targeting .NET Framework version 4.5.1.

Comment: Well where in the C# language specification do you see anything suggesting the compiler should do anything with `NoEqualityAttribute`? Basically, that's not a cross-language-implemented attribute. You could potentially write a Roslyn analyzer to catch calls like that though.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah, good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the C# language will not handle many F# specific features.  Most F# types, *when used from F#*, have different functionality.  For example, F# types are (by default) unable to be set to `null`, but in C#, you can declare and set them to `null` because the C# language doesn't understand any of the F# specific constructs. As you've discovered, equality and comparison guarantees, nullable guarantees and features, and more are all ignored by C# (and other CLR languages).

In practice, this is rarely a problem, as most people tend to keep the F# types within their F# code base, and pull in types from the BCL or C# projects and convert them to F# types (to add the safety guarantees) "at the API boundaries".

Comment: OK, then another solution might be to override `Object#Equals` and throw an exception from there, I suppose.

Comment: @Yawar That's a very bad idea.  The documentation for `Object.Equals` says that implementations must never throw exceptions, the result should be `true` or `false`.

Comment: @TheInnerLight hmm, I was afraid of that. OK, then the only solution is to override it intelligently to a correct and meaningful equality test for my type.

Comment: @Yawar In general, yes, that's the best option - unless you want to keep reference equality.